# Which type of function can be used to collect form data sent both from GET and POST method

Tags: php

Which type of function can be used to collect form data sent both from GET and POST method

this is a question please tell me the ans thanks

Comment: You're in need of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: You're looking for the `$_REQUEST` superglobal. Though you really should know whether data is coming from POST or GET and only allow data from one. Also keep in mind issues around the same key being available in both. Finally, it will only work (just as $_POST) with form encoded data.

Comment: Which type of function can be used to collect form data sent both from GET and POST method ? this is quesion which i answar so tell which funcation is ?i am not web pro

Comment: @Sana Again, you don't need a function. You access `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` as arrays.

Comment: @Sana `$_GET` & `$_POST` are arrays that can be accessed globally. You can access the values as, `$_POST['input_name']`

Comment: Also, if you don't understand what we mean by superglobals and arrays, then you either need to start learning PHP, or hire somebody to do the work.

Comment: if it really needs to be a function: `filter_input((INPUT_GET|INPUT_POST), 'search');`

Comment: i dont want learn php i just found ans  to write in exam

Comment: Briefly explain "Functions" in JavaScript with one programming example.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

$_GET for getting GET data.

$_POST for getting POST data.

Comment: what type of funcation is used ?

Comment: You don't need any function to get data. Simply use $_GET for getting all get data. Like you have a get parameter named 'name', you will get it like $_GET['name']. Got it?

Comment: like **www.example.com?name=lorem**  then you can receive like **$_GET['name'];** and if you echo this then you will get **lorem**

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST`- An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET, $_POST.`

**FirstPage.php**

```
<form ..... action='submit.php' ... >
    <input type='text' name='FirstName'>
</form>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php  
$name=$_REQUEST['FirstName'];  
echo $name;  
?>
```

Check this [$_REQUEST - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) and [$_REQUEST - W3-Resource](http://www.w3resource.com/php/super-variables/$_REQUEST.php)

Comment: Briefly explain "Functions" in JavaScript with one programming example.